# Graph partitioning optimization

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, nearest-neighbor

## The problem

I have a set of locations on a plane (actually they are *pins* in a KML file) and I want to partition this graph into subgraphs. Connectivity is pretty good - as with all real world road networks - so I assume that if two locations are close they have some kind of connection. The resulting set of subgraphs should adhere to these constraints:

- Every node has to be covered by a subgraph
- Every node should be in exactly 1 subgraph
- Every node within a subgraph should be close to each other (L2 norm distances)
- Every subgraph should contain at least 5 locations
- The amount of subgraphs should be minimal

Right now the amount of locations is no more than 100 so I thought about brute forcing through every possibility but this obviously won't scale well.

I thought about using some *k-Nearest-Neighbors* algorithm (e.g. using [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/)) but I can't get my head around where to start and how to extend/shrink the subgraphs on the way. Maybe it's possible to map this problem to another problem that can easily be solved with some numerical procedure (e.g. [Simplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm)) ...

Maybe someone has experience in this kind of optimization problems and is willing to help me find a solution? I don't have access to Mathematica/Matlab or the like ... but sufficient .NET programming skills and *hmm* Excel :-)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as there are multiple criteria that need to be appeased in the best possible way simultanously, it is usually starting to get difficult.

A numerical solution could work as follows: You could define yourself a utility function, that maps partitionings of your locations to positive real values, describing how "good" a partition is by assigning it a "rating" (good could be high "bad" could be near zero).

Once you have such a function assigning partitions their according "values", you simply need to optimize it and then you hopefully obtain a good solution if you defined your utility function reasonably. Evolutionary algorithms are good at that task since your utility function is probably analytically too complex to solve due to its discrete nature.

The problem is then only how you assign "values" to partitions via this utility function. This is then your task. It can be done for example by weighing each criterion with a factor and summing the results up, or even more complex functions (least squares etc.). The factors you use in the definition of the utility function are tuning parameters and can be varied until the result seems to be good.

Some CA software wold help a lot for testing if you can get your hands on one, bit I guess to obtain a black box solver for your partitioning problem, you need to implement the complete procedure yourself using a language of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, the approach seems reasonable - I imagine the rating function to be somewhat complicated :-)

Comment: Its as complicated as you want it to be. It could be very easy though, e.g. by simply summing up the rating for each criterion and optimising that. I have used a similar approach for a multi criterial optimisation problem in my thesis and it worked fine.